# Using reCAPTCHA on contact-form.php

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

reCaptcha is sending messages without activating the reCaptcha and last night I received over 300 messages a boot.

Help me please how to add so that only sent when the button is activated reCaptcha. Send sends works well but not activation reCaptcha.

To start contact.html within my template I have put this way:

```
<!-- Start formulario de contacto -->   
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h2>Formulario de contacto</h2>
                        <form action="php/contact-form.php" id="contact-form">

                            <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="contact-alert-success">
                                <strong>Mensaje enviado correctamente!</strong>  Muchas gracias, pronto nos pondremos en contacto con usted, normalmente nuestro tiempo de respuesta es inferior a 2 horas.
                            </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" id="contact-alert-error">
                                <strong>Error!</strong> A sucedido un error si lo desea puede contactarnos directamente en XXXX@tize.XXXX
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Nombre <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            value=""
                                            data-msg-required="Por favor introduzca su nombre"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            name="name" id="name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>eMail <span class="required">*</span>  </label>
                                        <input type="email" 
                                            value=""
                                            data-msg-required="Por favor introduzca su eMail"
                                            data-msg-email="Por favor introduzca un eMail válido"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            name="email"
                                            id="email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Asunto <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" 
                                            value=""
                                            data-msg-required="Por favor introduzca el asunto"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            name="subject"
                                            id="subject">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Mensaje <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <textarea
                                            data-msg-required="Por favor introduzca su mensaje"
                                            rows="10"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            name="message"
                                            id="message"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                    
                  <!-- Start Google Recaptcha -->
                     <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc88P4SAAAAANiT-ZXILUo-ET4xQmbivHy7uHc8"></div><br>
                  <!-- End Google Recaptcha -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Cargando...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>  
                    </div>
                   <!-- End formulario de contacto -->
```

And in php form to send the messages have this post with contact-form.php :

```
   <?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Enter your email address
$to = 'XXXX@tize.XX';

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

if($to) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'Name',
            'val' => $_POST['name']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Email address',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'Message',
            'val' => $_POST['message']
        )
    );

    $message = "";

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }

    $headers = '';
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
    } else{
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($arrResult);

} else {

    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    echo json_encode($arrResult);

}
?>
```

Picture of my form, If anyone wants to see my website please let me know and send you the link. Thank you very much. sending without activating the reCaptcha http://goo.gl/oSLQG9

Comment: Please remove all the code irrelevant to the question. This will help you get an answer quicker

Answer (score 0):

1.) Using your current provided code `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>` is missing and is required for recaptcha to work.

2.) Per Google's documentation on Re-Captcha, Google will send a response on a verified/non-verified submission in which you must use a $_GET call to evaluate the response for success / fail.

From Google Re-Captcha step 2 - server side integration:

> When your users submit the form where you integrated reCAPTCHA, you'll
>   get as part of the payload a string with the name
>   "g-recaptcha-response". In order to check whether Google has verified
>   that user, send a GET request with these parameters:
>
> URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
>   secret(required)  6LedHvoSAAAAAN4cRa8x1FaVsKPsMrs8SGMqp4ef
>   response(required)    The value of 'g-recaptcha-response'. remoteip   The
>   end user's ip address.

In short - I don't see the required SCRIPT linking in your code provided, I also see no implementation of a $_GET call to Google re-captcha to verifiy success/failure of the re-captcha entered by the user.

Be sure you are implimenting and using the tools/directions provided directly from Google to make your integration located here:

[Google Re-Captcha Site](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer.
But in the html document if I have given above what the script.
Why not put the document is very large.

What happens that my form works fine but does not work on reCaptcha. Send emails but do not give it to activate the reCaptcha.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I can't see link and declaration of private-key and public-key in it.
I myself use this to handle it:

1.Place the google-recaptcha file in a directory.
2.declare on contact.php, as:

```
require_once('../recpatcha_google.php');
$publickey = '6LcZIfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$privatekey = '6LcZIf8Sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

3.to check if user verify and pass the captcha:

```
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],strip_tags($_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field']),strip_tags($_POST['recaptcha_response_field']));
if (!$resp->is_valid) { //if not true ......
................
}
```

4.call the captcha inside your form, as:

```
<?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?>
```

Note: Do not forget to register your site with WWW or without WWW to make sure everything runs OK.

Comment: Hello, first thank you very much for your help and for your time.
I have put the domain properly without www.
Then I followed your steps but something happens that I miss.
I put everything as you say but I happen to not send anything now.

Comment: In the contact-php I put the public and private key as you said and put a little below the code you told me also leaving everything well.  http://goo.gl/FYXYCW

Comment: After the html document above all put what you said. I'm not sure if that's where you want to wear. I put just before the </head> http://goo.gl/vP6Izp But does not send the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I put everything inside the contact.php document and does not work. How odd. Thanks and sorry for the roll and see if I can solve.    http://goo.gl/Rjx4KK   Pictured put as added thus far but the form does nothing, will not work.